# WPF documentation exists on MSDN?

Tags: wpf-controls

Am I missing something or is there no documentation of WPF controls?

When I look at MSDN, it says to reference System.Windows.Controls
(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752069.aspx), but this is for winforms?

Where can I find the WPF object model?

Answer (score 3):

[Bam!](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.aspx)

Documentation for all WPF classes.

Comment: I don't see where this give me all methods, properties etc for a particular control.

I'm looking for equivalent to winform treeview control :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The URL you provide in your question ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752069.aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752069(v=vs.90).aspx)) is, in fact, the documentation path for WPF controls, *not* for WinForm controls (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.aspx for WinForms). To get to the members of Treeview, for example, walkthrough `Control Library >> TreeView` then again click `Treeview` in the **Reference** section. I think a subtle point of confusion to Winform-only developers is to think that `System.Windows.Controls` is for WinForm, when it is actually for WPF.

The URL Kevin provided (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.aspx) is also an important one to know: it is the main documentation path for all of WPF.

Finally, if you want to get a sense of the similarities and differences between controls in WinForm and WPF, take a look at my article on Simple-Talk.com
[From WinForm to WPF: A Quick Reference Guide](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/from-winform-to-wpf-a-quick-reference-guide/).